# How do I detect when the browser has finished downloading a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, browser, download

I really hope someone can help me. I'm having real difficulty looking for a Jquery or Javascript solution that checks if a file has been downloaded.
I have a spinner which displays on the screen while some data is gathered and put into an excel spreadsheet. However, once the file is downloaded the spinner keeps on going. So basically I need to find a way to stop the spinner once the file is downloaded. Desperate for some help!
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o3TK.jpg)

Comment: Once it's *finished downloading* or once it *starts downloading*? Normally you wouldn't care when it finishes - you just hand off the data to the browser and that's it, it takes care of everting afterwards, so you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Can I see your code for that download method? Maybe you can set the div that contains the spinner to hidden after the promise has been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to tell without seeing the code that triggers the download process.

But generally, it is not possible to know when the download **finishes**, as the downloading process involves the OS, the browser and not only your website.

It is may be possible though to know when the download **starts**, or more precisely, to know when the download is about to start, because again, when the download starts, it is not your website's business any more.

You just need to add a listener somewhere between the spreadsheet file being ready, and calling the download procedure. Consider posting your code so that we can work it out.